# Show if the sequence $s_n :=\sum\limits _{j= 2^n}^{2^{n+1} }{ \frac 1 { j \sqrt [ n ]{ j } } } $ has a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm still onto reviewing some Calculus 1.
and I want to show wether the sequence $$s_n :=\sum _{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1 {j\sqrt[ n ]{j}}$$ has a limit or not.

Since $s_n =\sum\limits_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1 { j^{\frac 1 n +1} }$ 
looks like a geometric sum it probably has one but i couldnt find it yet.

Comment: 1) Are you able to prove that $\{s_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is both monotonic and bounded?

Comment: 2) Once 1) is settled, do you need an explicit form for the limit or a proof of existence is enough?

Comment: 3) Just in case, this might be pretty useful: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{dx}{x^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{2}\log 2.$$

Comment: I got the monotony and the lower bound, but struggling to find the upper bound. Existence is enough but still very helpful for explicit form

Comment: You are summing $2^n+1$ terms and each one of them is at most $\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^n}$, hence a simple upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks was helpful! If u like u can make an answer out of it

Comment: So, in the end, your Calculus 1 knowledge includes the Hermite-Hadamard inequality? Since this is highly unusual, you should have mentioned the fact in your question, if only to avoid that some poor users try to delineate tech-free approaches to your problem, all for nothing... And of course, you checked for yourself that HH inequality is indeed proving what someone told you it proves, right? Good.

Comment: No my Calc 1 knowledge didnt include the HH inequality, but I still understood how it solves my problem. But i get our point and i have to say it isnt for nothing, I actually think that ur apporach is better since it uses only Calc 1 stuff which i want to review. I gave the accpect because I saidt to make an answer out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple upper and lower bounds allow to bypass any advanced knowledge. To wit, note that, for every $2^n\leqslant j\leqslant2^{n+1}$, $$2\leqslant\sqrt[n] j\leqslant2\cdot2^{1/n}$$ hence, for every $n$, $$\frac12\cdot t_n\leqslant s_n\leqslant\frac12\cdot\frac1{2^{1/n}}\cdot t_n$$ where $$t_n=\sum_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac1j=\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^n}\sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}j$$ The last sum on the RHS is a Riemann sum of the function $f(x)=\frac1x$ on the interval $(1,2)$ hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=0+\int_1^2f(x)dx=\ln2$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac12\cdot\ln2$$

Comment: Fully agree with your opening sentence. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed, simply taking seriously what the OP say they are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $n$ is a large natural number, the difference between 
$$ S_n=\sum_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad I_n=\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{dx}{x^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$$
is negligible. Indeed, by invoking the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) we have that such difference is bounded by $\frac{4}{2^n}$. $I_n$ can be computed in a explicit way and the problem boils down to computing:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right).$$
The Taylor series of $2^{-1-x}$ at the origin is given by $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\log 2}{2}x+O(x^2)$, hence the previous limit equals $\color{red}{\frac{\log 2}{2}}\approx 0.34657359$.